# Why are Ramanujan graphs named after Ramanujan?

Tags: graph-theory, soft-question, ho.history-overview, expanders

I recently taught expanders, and introduced the notion of Ramanujan graphs.
Michael Forbes asked why they are called this way, and I had to admit I don't know. 
Anyone?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

To add some content to the answers here, I'll explain briefly what Ramanujan's conjecture is.

First of all, Ramanujan's conjecture is actually a theorem, proved by Eichler and Igusa.  Here is one way to state it.  Let $r_m(n)$ denote the number of integral solutions to the quadratic equation $x_1^2 + m^2 x_2^2 + m^2 x_3^2 + m^2 x_4^2 = n$.  If $m=1$, that $r_m(n) > 0$ was of course proved by Legendre, but Jacobi gave the exact count: $r_1(n) = 8 \sum_{d \mid n, 4 \not \mid d} d$.  Nothing similarly exact is known for larger $m$ but Ramanujan conjectured the bound: $r_m(n) = c_m \sum_{d \mid n} d + O(n^{1/2 + \epsilon})$ for every $\epsilon > 0$, where $c_m$ is a constant dependent only on $m$.

Lubtozky, Phillips and Sarnak constructed their expanders based on this result.  I'm not familiar with the details of their analysis but the basic idea, I believe, is to construct a Cayley graph of $PSL(2,Z_q)$ for a prime $q$ that $1 \bmod 4$, using generators determined by every sum-of-four-squares decomposition of $p$, where $p$ is a quadratic residue modulo $q$.  Then, they relate the eigenvalues of this Cayley graph to $r_{2q}(p^k)$ for integer powers $k$.

A reference, other than the Lubotzky-Phillips-Sarnak paper itself, is Noga Alon's brief description in [Tools from Higher Algebra](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.101.5803&rep=rep1&type=pdf).

Comment: nice ! great answer.

Answer (score 21):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Ramanujan_graph&oldid=383972239) delivers this answer rather promptly. Quoting

> Constructions of Ramanujan graphs are often algebraic. Lubotzky, Phillips and Sarnak show how to construct an infinite family of $p+1$-regular Ramanujan graphs, whenever $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ is a prime. Their proof uses the [Ramanujan conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan%E2%80%93Petersson_conjecture), which led to the name of Ramanujan graphs.

The paper referred to is [*Ramanujan graphs*](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02126799);
A. Lubotzky, R. Phillips and P. Sarnak, COMBINATORICA Volume 8, Number 3 (1988), 261-277,  DOI: 10.1007/BF02126799.

Comment: the question is: what is the ramanujan conjecture

Comment: It is sometimes much better to preserve links when you quote.

Comment: Indeed. I underestimated the seriousness of the question.